# Group_by error "no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, group-by

I am trying to add median, min, max using dplyr "summarise" with piping
When I use:

```
mustelid_lengths %/% group_by(gender, species) %/% summarise(median(length), min(length), max(length))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"
```

[image]

I was expecting summaries as in the attached image.

*note my data table is called mustelid_lengths whereas in the example the data table is called mustelid

[image]

Comment: Your code as shared shows `%/%` but the magrittr pipe is actually `%>%`

Comment: Hi Laura Peirson, weclome to SO. In addition to the comment above, please do not add data or example outputs as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the example text in a codeblock. For the data,  run `dput(mustelid_lengths)` or `dput(head(mustelid_lengths),20)` if your dataset is large and copy the result into a codeblock. That way we get an exact copy of data, which helps make diagnosing issues much easier. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I did not catch that I put "/" instead of ">". I also had to use dplyr:: before group_by and summarize. Thanks for the tips on not using images!